# How we can screen sharing of particular portion of screen and customize screen in Web

Tags: javascript, screen, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have need to customize screen share of particular portion of screen part and need to customize fix part of agora please give some solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do this from the Agora Web SDK yet. You can use our desktop versions for [Mac](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/screensharing_mac?platform=macOS#share-the-whole-or-part-of-a-screen-by-specifying-display-id) or [Windows](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/screensharing_windows?platform=windows#share-the-whole-or-part-of-a-screen-by-specifying-screenrect) and add this feature natively using Agora's SDK.

You may have to work with a canvas covering the whole screen and share just a small part through JavaScript.

- [Documentation for screen-sharing on the web](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/screensharing_web_ng?platform=Web)